# Android - Communicating from Activity to fragment that it hosts

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently I have been diving into the Fragment world: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

I understand that by creating a listener in the fragment and then implementing it in the Activity which hosts the fragment is a great way to communicate from the fragment to the Activity, but how do I get communicate back from the activity to the fragment? Another listener? Perhaps I don't fully understand what the listener is doing. Any help with this topic explaining how to communicate from activity to fragment would be much appreciated!

P.S. I am currently converting an activity (B) that I made into a fragment. I use to do some intent.putExtra("value") from Activity A before starting Activity B so this is what I am looking to replace... Probably doesn't help you at all but I thought I'd try and put it into perspective what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the solution, lol. I'll do some checks to make sure this works and confirm it later.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        wid = b.getString("wid");
        rid = b.getString("rid");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryfragment, container, false);
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you do when you create an Activity, you can pass a `Bundle` to a `Fragment`.

There's an example on how to do that on the [Fragment class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29).

```
/**
 * Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to
 * show the text at 'index'.
 */
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

Use `getArguments()` to get the `Bundle` back.